# JavaScript Prototypal Object Efficiency in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, prototype

I was wondering which of the following would be more efficient in a `Node API`

```
function LoginController() {
    this.model= new Model();
};
LoginController.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    this.model.doSomethingToo();
}
```

versus this:

```
function LoginController() {
};
LoginController.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    new Model().doSomethingToo();
}
```

As far as I understand prototypal objects in scenario #1 I would create a new *Model* every time I call `new LoginController()`.

In scenario #2 I would create a new *Model* only once when creating the first `new LoginController()`. All next new instances would **not** create an other *Model*, because it was already created in the prototypal function.

Is that correct?

Comment: No, that is not correct. The second scenario would create a new `Model` every time `loginControllerInstance.doSomething` is executed.

Comment: The method itself, `doSomething`, is defined only once with the `prototype`, but its contents are still reevaluated with each call. With #2, every use of `login.doSomething()` would create a `new Model()`.

Comment: Is this actually what you were asking? or was there a problem you were trying to solve. Seems kinda silly to have an answer so short.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, that is not correct. The second scenario would create a new `Model` instance every time `loginControllerInstance.doSomething` is executed.

However, there are a few other ways that you could do this, depending on what exactly `Model.prototype.doSomethingToo` does, for example:

```
function LoginController() {
    this.model = {};
};
LoginController.prototype.doSomething = function() {
    Model.prototype.doSomethingToo.call(this.model);
}
```

This would never initialize a `Model` instance, instead, it would simply execute `Model.prototype.doSomethingToo` with a `this` equal to `this.model`

What's best will depend on what you are trying to do and how each constructor/prototype is setup.

Comment: Thanks. Currently learning JS and totally overlooked that. The `.call()` advice is pretty neat, too.